# NGINX server configuration

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I am trying to configure nginx and have the following configuration in:

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
    server_name firstproj.dev www.firstproj.dev;
    root /var/www/firstProj/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

where both app.php and app_dev.php are files in /var/www/firstProj/web/ folder created by symfony with no further modifications.

firstProj is a symfony project that I am currently working on and what I fail to understand here is:

1. Why when i access www.firstproj.dev I get

   > Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
2. Why when I access www.firstproj.dev/app_dev.php everything is ok and I can also access my routes (eg: www.firstproj.dev/app_dev.php/homepage works perfectly fine and returns the expected response from the action in my controller)
3. Why when I access www.firstproj.dev/app.php I get 404 error.

I want it to work with www.firstproj.dev/homepage with no app_dev.php there but I cannot make it work that way.
Furthermore, if I access

http://localhost

I get:

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed
>   and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

I apologize if this is a rather dumb question but I'm a beginner as far server configuration is concerned.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you add firstproj.dev and www.firstproj.dev in the etc/hosts ?

Comment: Yes! They both are in the /etc/hosts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're finding that your `app_dev.php` works but `app.php` does not work?

I've had this happen in the past and there are a few things worth checking.

1. Copy the contents of `app_dev.php` into `app.php` and see if `www.firstproj.dev/app.php` or `www.firstproj.dev` work. If it works then you know it's not a problem with NGINX but instead a problem with your Symfony Setup.
2. Have you created a `cache` or `logs` directory for `prod` or only for `dev`? Are they writable by `www-data`?
3. Have you checked `/var/log/nginx/project_error.log` to see if any error is showing up when trying to access `app.php`?
4. At the top of the `app.php` file add in the line `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Now when you try to access the production version do you see any error?
5. Try clearing the cache for production. Depending how you have you server setup (Are you using `ACL` or `CHOWN/CHMOD` for your cache/log files?) You can run something like `sudo su -u www-data php bin/console cache:clear --env prod`

Comment: 1. If I copy the content of app_dev into app, then it works
2. They both exist and are writable by www-data
3. project_error.log is empty
4. I did and nothing shows up

!!!
BAM
This was it
5. When I tried to clear the cache I got this error:
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                
  Cannot load resource...

So I used a third party bundle which was registered in AppKernel only in the dev mode. Not in prod mode so that was the problem.

Thank you very much!
Problem solved :)